# PHP help requesting info from submitted forms

Tags: php, curl

I am having trouble with some thing that was created a while back which checks if a car has a valid MOT and tax through the gov.uk site, i would appreciate some other eyes on it to see what i am doing wrong.

I just cant seem  to figure it out. This exact code used to work but the site has recently been changed slightly which has stopped it working altogether.

I use this to check automatically if my employees cars are taxed and MOT'd, having lots of employees it can become a pain in the backside checking manually..

So basically i login to https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle send over the car reg and Confirm_True then grab the results from the https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ViewVehicle page

But it has now all of a sudden stopped working.

Thanks in advance for any help / advice.

```
    <?
$Vrm = "ND17 PXK";

$url = 'https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle';
$fields = array(
    'Vrm' => urlencode($Vrm),
    'Correct_True' => urlencode("True")
);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$value = explode("value=\"", $result);
$value = explode("\"", $value[1]);

$url = 'https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ViewVehicle';
$fields = array(
    'Vrm' => urlencode($Vrm),
    'viewstate' => urlencode($value[0])
);
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$res=$dom->loadHTML($result);

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$class = 'isInvalid';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

if ( !$divs ) { echo "issue"; }

foreach($divs as $div)
{
    $dateSplit = explode(":", $div->nodeValue);
    echo $dateSplit[0] . " " . $dateSplit[1] . " ";

    $date1 = new DateTime(date(d) . " " . date ( M ) . " " . date( Y ));
    $date2 = new DateTime($dateSplit[1]);
    
    if ( $date1 > $date2 ) $exp = "Expired";
    else $exp = "Valid for another";

    $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
    echo $exp . " " . $diff . "<BR><BR>";
}

$class = 'isValid';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

if ( !$divs ) { echo "issue"; }

foreach($divs as $div)
{
    $dateSplit = explode(":", $div->nodeValue);
    echo $dateSplit[0] . "<BR>" . $dateSplit[1] . "<BR>";

    $date1 = new DateTime(date(d) . " " . date ( M ) . " " . date( Y ));
    $date2 = new DateTime($dateSplit[1]);
    $diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");

    if ( $date1 > $date2 ) $exp = "Expired";
    else $exp = "Valid for another";

    echo $exp . " " . $diff . "<BR><BR>";
}
?>
```

Comment: "Stopped working" what happens? What should have happened instead? Does the page break, bad results? Can't ascertain a cause of a problem if we don't know the problem. Does your PHP version support short open tags? `<?`

Comment: "*seems im now getting no results back*" that's the problem. So what do you get if you do `var_dump($result);` That will show what is coming back.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking your code and in my local environment I did the following changes:

In the beginning:

```
<php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$fields_string = '';
```

- Added php tag to avoid possible errors, added error reporting for allow me to better debugging and declared `fields_string` (avoid warnings).

With the error message ON, I saw that I have to install the `PHP-CURL` library.

Once installed I have a *response* from the URL, like:

> '     (function(){
>       var securemsg;
>       var dosl7_common; window["bobcmn"] = "1011200000002200000001300000021application/x-www-form-urlencoded3000000081d015909300000008TSPD_101300000011%2fConfirmVehicle300000000300000006/TSPD/300000008TSPD_101300000005https30000001fVrm=ND17+PXK&Corre'...
>   (length=27391)

Then, I saw that you are doing this:

```
$value = explode("value=\"", $result);
$value = explode("\"", $value[1]);
```

But in the array position $value[1] there is no results, you should do **$value[0]**.

Then, with this changes you could follow developing, process the returned infomation and know where are your errors.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks will take a look asap

Comment: Thanks again for your help, still getting the same error message on both pages, i think they've added some protection so if visitor isnt javascript enabled then it wont work. Gonna have to have a re think on this one i think

Comment: that is still a super shitty unreliable way to get the viewstate. do `$value = (@DOMDocument::loadHTML($result))->getElementById("viewstate")->getAttribute("value");` instead. much more reliable, your explode code will break once they put another input tag (so it's no longer [1], perhaps [2]), or if they remove 1 (so it becomes [0] instead of [1]), or if it includes any html entities, explode() won't decode html entities for you, DOMDocument will. your explode code will even break if they put a space between `value` and `=`, eg `value ="foo"` , or `value= "foo"`, or `value = "foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

you require certain cookies to access the results, these cookies are generated and set by a highly complex, and intentionally obfuscated piece of javascript that you obtain when you try to access https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle without any cookies, looking a little something like

```
securemsg = {
        IlS: function(S) {
            return securemsg[L(28897)](securemsg._j((_(713), 0), S, _(104) ? 1 : 0), function() {
                return String[I(185, 197, 194, 192, 150, 187, 180, 197, 150, 194, 183, 184)](Math[L(26206011)](Math[L(1650473734)]() * (_(160) ? 256 : 270) + (_(39) ? 1 : 0)) % (_(905) ? 331 : 256))
            })[L(918239)]("")
        },
        s_: function(S) {
            return ((S & (_(163) ? 255 : 361)) << (_(968) ? 33 : 24) | (S & (_(383) ? 65280 : 62377)) << (_(767) ? 5 : 8) | S >> (_(79) ? 8 : 4) & (_(301) ? 65280 : 33117) | S >> (_(635) ? 17 : 24) & (_(366) ? 255 : 291)) >>> (_(803), 0)
        },
        L5: function(S, J) {
            for (var l = "", O = (_(206), 0); O <
                S[L(1294399205)]; O++) l += String["\u0066ro\x6dCh\u0061rC\x6fde"](S[I(182, 187, 180, 197, 150, 194, 183, 184, 148, 199)]((O + S[L(1294399205)] - J) % S[L(1294399205)]));
            return l
        },
```

while it is possible to re-implement the algorithm in PHP, and extract the data from the HTML (in fact, it looks like  the vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle devs themselves implemented the algorithm both in javascript and in ASP.net for verification purposes), it's almost certainly not worth the hassle, it will probably be much easier to just feed the javascript to a javascript engine, and fetch the `document.cookie` javascript variable, and feed it to CURLOPT_COOKIE. as for which javascript engine to use, you might be able to get away with using a javascript interpreter written in PHP (like https://github.com/jakubkulhan/js2php ), but afaik, there are no feature-complete PHP JS engines to date, so you might need to use an external/non-php javascript engine, for example [Google's V8 javascript engine](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Getting%20Started%20with%20Embedding).